# How can I secure Windows from heartbleed

Tags: heartbleed

I just fixed my openssl version on debianwheezy and updated my android device away from version 1.1.1 but the only thing that is missing is my windows-PC. My question now is, how is windows 7 professional, 64 bit  exactly affected or is it affected and how can I fix it in one turn (like in linux) or can I just patch single applications? so, how can I secure my windows from heartbleed. sorry for my incompetence, I´m pretty much a beginner with protocols and internet-security. 
Thanks very much in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, on Windows, you must identify and update affected applications individually as there is no shared OpenSSL used across the system.

The good news is that Windows itself is not vulnerable as it has its own SSL/TLS stack, and many Windows applications do not use OpenSSL. For example, none of the popular browsers use OpenSSL for transport.

Comment: oh okay I´m released, but I´ve heard that google wants to switch to openssl, will chrome also be concerned?

Comment: Whether or not Chrome starts using OpenSSL doesn't really matter for Heartbleed, since if they switch it would be to a version that isn't vulnerable.